# Connect to SQL server instance from my own application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am developing a windows software as a clone of SQL server management studio, but I am not clear how my own application will connect to SQL server database engine and run queries, as SQL server management studio connect to DB engine from the object explorer. I have searched for every possible solution but not got any help.

Things I need to provide from my software:

1) connect to SQL server database engine
2) display list of databases
3) run queries on the selected database

Comment: Wait a moment... you are writing a DB management application, and you are still unsure about some of the fundamental architectural points? I don't think SO is the place for your question, but I just had to ask...

Comment: what's wrong with `SQL Server Management Studio` ?

Comment: @PeterAbolins, I have worked with SSMS for creating databases but not know the internal working of how SSMS work with database engine

Comment: @Squirrel, I am trying to develop a kind of software where the basic queries, such as select, update, delete, and some stored procedures will be generated automatically for user when he/she will select the particular database. My application will read the schema of db and generate scripts automatically, that's what I want.

Comment: Good Luck to you

Comment: This is like driving a car for a short while, and then suddenly wanting to build a new car from scratch, without having any idea how an engine works. But, in the same vein as what @Squirrel said, I too wish you the best of luck...